# Object prototype methods versus values

Tags: javascript

I am a little perplexed about what is going on with my code, here is what I have so far:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = this.name;
Person.prototype.displayName = function() {
    return this.name;
}


var Sethen = new Person("Sethen");

console.log(Sethen.getName);
console.log(Sethen.displayName());
```

I am curious as to why `getName` doesn't give me the `this.name` value and only logs blank, while the `displayName` method gives me the correct value.  `getName` is a property of my prototype object, so my thought process was that I could grab it like this.

Why does `getName` not log the value of `Sethen`?  How would I go about grabbing that information like a regular property? Must I use a method?

Comment: If you're going to downvote give a reason.  Contribute to this community constructively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the value of `this` isn't what you think it is when that code is run. `this` is probably equal to the global object (i.e. `window`).

Since you're calling `displayName` and setting the context by prefixing it with an instance of the `Person` object, `this` is set correctly inside of the function and you get the person's name out.

Of course, you could always access the `name` property directly (`Sethen.name`).

Comment: How would I go about grabbing that information like a regular property?  Must I use a method?

Comment: I believe so, yes, unless you define the property inside of the `Person` constructor.

Comment: Can't you call `Sethen.name` directly?

Comment: While @AndrewWhitaker answer is correct, `this` refers to the global object, you can call `Sethen.name` directly without tying it to a method.  I was overwriting the local variable with something else in the prototype.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  The issue is that getName is assigned it's value long before any `Person` object is ever created.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're saying that an object should be created before it's prototype methods/values are??

Comment: @jfriend00: I don't see what difference a person object existing would make in this case, unless I'm misunderstanding. Even if an object of type `Person` did exist, `this` would still be incorrect wouldn't it? In fact, the second paragraph of your answer says as much.

Comment: Like I said, I think the issue here was that `this.name` was pointing to the `window` object as you said.  All I needed was to grab the property from the object created.. Which would be `Sethen.name`.  There was no reason for me to create a method in this case unless I am trying to do method chaining or something.

Comment: @SethenMaleno - no, I'm saying that you can only assign a prototype values that exist at the time of the creation of the prototype (before any individual objects have been created).  You can put static (unchanging values) into the prototype that already exist or you can put functions.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - `this.name` only exists in the context of a `Person` object.  There is no `Person` object yet at the time the `prototype` is assigned its `.getName` property and `this` certainly doesn't point to a `Person` object so the code simply won't do anything you want.  In fact, in ES5 `strict` mode, this code will even generate a javascript error.

Comment: @jfriend00: I understand (and agree with) everything in your comment. What I don't understand is where my answer contradicts with any of it.

Comment: I think you guys are saying the same thing now.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - the main issue is that is no `Person` object yet when the code that assigned `this.name` is run.  That's a conceptual problem with the code's design.  Your answer does not explain that you simply can't assign a prototype data value like this at all.  Your answer makes it sound like it's a garden variety issue with the way things are called so that `this` is wrong.  While `this` is wrong, the main issue here is that you can't access instance data at the initial construction of the prototype and you never explain what the real problem with the code is.

Comment: @jfriend00: I think if you recognize that `this` isn't what you think it is, it logically follows that there's a conceptual problem with the code's design.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - yes, but you didn't explain what the problem was with the design.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `getName` is not a function, but a property that is assigned a value when `Person.prototype.getName` is first assigned before a `Person` object is ever constructed.  So, there is no way that it could possibly contain the value of any particular Person object.

You simply cannot access instance data of an object at the time you are creating the prototype because no `Person` object exists yet and thus there is no instance data yet and thus `this` doesn't point to a `Person` object.

Instead, `Person.prototype.getName = this.name;` is assigning the `prototype` object a value of `this.name` which in your code is either `window.name` or in strict mode will cause an error because `this` will be undefined.

The prototype can be assigned functions or any data that already exists during your code initialization.  Things assigned to the prototype will have the same value for all objects of that type that you create.  This is why it's most useful to assign them functions/methods.

You could implement it this way to get the value of a given Person object:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName() = function() { 
    return this.name;
}

var Sethen = new Person("Sethen");

console.log(Sethen.getName());
```

The other option is to just access the `.name` property directly:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var Sethen = new Person("Sethen");
console.log(Sethen.name);
```

Comment: Or you could just call `Sethen.name` without tying it to a method.  That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @SethenMaleno - yes, I was working towards that too and have added that to my answer now.